# Monitoring stacked ensemble models with vetiver

Tags: r, stack, monitor, tidymodels, vetiver

I developed a stacked ensemble model using the tidymodels workflow and I want to monitor the performance of this model from time to time using vetiver. However, it seems the stacked model object isn't supported yet.

Please see the code snippet below

```
library(tidymodels)
library(vetiver)
library(pins)
library(arrow)
library(tidyverse)
library(bonsai)
library(stacks)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)



b <- board_folder(path = "pins-r/")
model <- vetiver_pin_read(board = b, name = "dcp_ibese_truck_arrival", 
                      version = "20230110T094207Z-69661")

trips <- read_parquet("../IbeseLivePosition/ml_data/data_to_monitor_model.parquet")

trips %<>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(DateTimeReceived))

original_metrics <- 
  vetiver::augment(model, new_data = trips)
```

*Error: No augment method for objects of class butchered_linear_stack*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looks like stacks doesn't yet have `augment` methods; I have [opened an issue here](https://github.com/tidymodels/stacks/issues/173) to track this feature.